# passing value by reference on C++

Tags: c++, ns-3

I am trying to understand what the arguments are for this method in a class from ns-3.

void ns3::OnOffHelper::SetAttribute (   std::string     name,
const AttributeValue &  value 
)

I was able to pass the first argument, but I am not sure what the second argument should be. Does it mean I have to pass a pointer value for the second argument?

Thanks,
BZ

Comment: Perhaps reading this may help: [Reference declarations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference)

Comment: Thank you, that makes it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, pass it how you would pass a normal variable.
The difference is that the variable is passed by reference and not by value so any changes the function `SetAttribute` makes to `value` will still be visible once the function returns. In this case however, its `const &` which promises you that it won't change `value`, it will only use it's information. This is usually done to prevent expensive copies (before C++11).

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot.